# Angular: including a html template as a part of whole

Tags: html, angular

Let say I have 10 objects in angular.

and this is what I have so far:

**main.TS**

```
item_display(data){         
   this.items = data;       
};
```

**main.html**

```
 <div class="my_items" *ngFor="let item of items;">
    <div class="item_name">{{item[0]}}</div>
    <div class="item_weight">{{item[1]}}</div>
    <div class="item_height">{{item[2]}}</div>
    <div class="item_color">{{item[3]}}</div>
    <div class="item_width">{{item[4]}}</div>
 </div>
```

Then instead of displaying all 10, I want to only display even numbered items and odd number items separately by the following:

```
<div class="mysieiu" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
   <div *ngIf="i % 2 == 0"> 
     Odd Number: 
      <div class="item_name">{{item[0]}}</div>
      <div class="item_weight">{{item[1]}}</div>
      <div class="item_height">{{item[2]}}</div>
      <div class="item_color">{{item[3]}}</div>
      <div class="item_width">{{item[4]}}</div>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="i % 2 == 1"> 
     Even Number: 
      <div class="item_name">{{item[0]}}</div>
      <div class="item_weight">{{item[1]}}</div>
      <div class="item_height">{{item[2]}}</div>
      <div class="item_color">{{item[3]}}</div>
      <div class="item_width">{{item[4]}}</div>
   </div>                   
</div>
```

**ISSUE:**

Issue is that now I am repeating lot of codes and I want to clean this up by making a template that I can just simply call it.

So, let say I make a html template called "item_template.html" as below:

**item_template.html**

```
 <div class="item_name">{{item[0]}}</div>
 <div class="item_weight">{{item[1]}}</div>
 <div class="item_height">{{item[2]}}</div>
 <div class="item_color">{{item[3]}}</div>
 <div class="item_width">{{item[4]}}</div>
```

Now, I am stuck. How would I incorporate this new template into the main.html?

Comment: This is not angularjs (version 2+)

Comment: Opps. Wrong word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new component, for example item-detail:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component(
  selector: 'item-detail',
  template: `
    <div class="item_name">{{item[0]}}</div>
    <div class="item_weight">{{item[1]}}</div>
    <div class="item_height">{{item[2]}}</div>
    <div class="item_color">{{item[3]}}</div>
    <div class="item_width">{{item[4]}}</div>
  `
)
export class ItemDetailComponent {
  @Input() item: Array<any>;
}
```

Register this component in the declarations section of your module.  Then in your main html you would consume it as:

```
<div class="mysieiu" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
   <div *ngIf="i % 2 == 0"> 
     Odd Number: 
      <item-detail [item]="item"></item-detail>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="i % 2 == 1"> 
     Even Number: 
      <item-detail [item]="item"></item-detail>
   </div>                   
</div>
```

Comment: Also, instead of 2 `*ngIf`, you can use `if/else` :)